# What are the benefits of ES5 Strict being a fully statically scoped language?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, specifications

Unlike the default language (ES5 Default), the strict mode of JavaScript (ES5 Strict) provides restrictions which make the language fully statically scoped. The default language isn't fully statically scoped, because of these violations:

- assignments to undeclared variables dynamically create implied global variables,
- the `with` statement (objects are dynamic in JavaScript, so the JS engine cannot know prior to evaluation which names are properties of the object, and which names are bound to the environment),
- `eval` calls can dynamically add names to the environment,
- the `delete` operator can dynamically delete names from the environment (works for implied global variables, and variables added via eval calls).

Source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq4FpMe6cRs&t=42m48s

I can see that full static scoping aids performance, since the JS engine can bind the variables (or at least most of them) (to names in lexical environments) prior to evaluation. Also, I guess, the program becomes more readable and less likely to cause confusion.

However, my understanding of the benefits of full static scope is not nearly as complete as I'd like it to be.

Comment: I think the design aim of the strict mode was that you have to declare your variable scopes explictly. So, this not only improves readability, scripts also become less errorprone. Instead of silently <s>failing</s> creating implied global variables, you get a meaningful exception, which helps you to debug the code more easily.